# checking if a string is subsequence of another string

Tags: python, algorithm, subsequence

Two strings M and W are given, need to check if one is subsequence of another.

I tried the following:

```
def filterr(bigStr,smallStr,i):
res=''
for char in bigStr:
    if(char in smallStr[i:]):
        i+=1
        res+=char
return res

m,w=input().split()
if(m==w):
    print('YES')
else:
    if(len(m)<len(w)):
        m,w=w,m
    s=filterr(m,w,0)
    if(s==w): print('YES')
    else: print('NO')
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my above code. It's not working for some unknown testcases (on a coding site). I have tried all types of inputs that I can think of and it is giving the correct answer for all of them.
Examples:

i/p: "john johanna"         o/p: YES

i/p: "ira ira"              o/p: YES

i/p: "kayla jayla"          o/p: NO

Please help in finding why my code is not working for some unknown testcases.

Comment: How is 'john' a subsequence of 'johanna'?

Comment: @MrSmith42 Subsequence is not substring. A subsequence of a string is a new string that is formed from the original string by deleting some (can be none) of the characters without disturbing the relative positions of the remaining characters. (i.e., "ace" is a subsequence of "abcde" while "aec" is not).

Comment: @MrSmith42  any of the given strings can be the subsequence of another. It's not that we need to  check if only 'first' string is the subsequence of 'second' string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about a test case:

```
m = "baab"
w = "ab"
```

With your filterr implementation, `filterr("baab", "ab", 0)` will return "bb" not "ab". Since "bb" != "ab", it will not think "ab" as a subsequence of "baab". But it is clear that "ab" is a subsequence of "baab".

To solve this subsequence problem, I'd recommend using two pointers approach.

```py
# assume len(s) <= len(t)
def is_subsequence(s, t):
    p1 = 0
    p2 = 0
    while p1 < len(s) and p2 < len(t):
        if s[p1] == t[p2]:
            p1 += 1
            p2 += 1
        else:
            p2 += 1
            
    return p1 == len(s)
```

Answer (score -2):

you will understand what is wrong with your code after reading this solution
Try this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-two-strings-find-first-string-subsequence-second/